# Inner Join Query in Access2013 SQL view

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in access 2013"2017FrenchProjectData" and "NewModes" I am trying to use the 'invoicemode / service level' column that is in both fields to update the 'French Project Mode' that is only in the New Modes table. I am using the below however i keep getting a syntax error (missing operator) message.

```
UPDATE     [2017FrenchProjectData]
SET        [2017FrenchProjectData].[FrenchProjectMode]=newmodes.[frenchprojectmode]
          ,[2017FrenchProjectData].[BasicMode]=[newmodes].[modedesc]
FROM       [2017FrenchProjectData]
INNER JOIN NewModes 
ON         2017FrenchProjectData.[ Invoice Mode / Service Level]=Newmodes.[ Invoice Mode / Service Level]
```

Comment: I believe the syntax for Access requires the INNER JOIN after the SET with no FROM.

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` syntax for Access is a little curious. It doesn't have a `From` clause. Instead, tables and joins are specified after specifying `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE     [2017FrenchProjectData]
INNER JOIN NewModes 
ON         [2017FrenchProjectData].[ Invoice Mode / Service Level]=Newmodes.[ Invoice Mode / Service Level]
SET        [2017FrenchProjectData].[FrenchProjectMode]=newmodes.[frenchprojectmode]
          ,[2017FrenchProjectData].[BasicMode]=[newmodes].[modedesc]
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik. It seems to be not liking the ON command as it gave me the synax error after adjusting to the above. I am getting "Syntax Error (Missing operator) in query expression '2017FrenchProjectData.[Invoice Mode / Service Level]=Newmodes.[invoice Mode / Service Level]

Comment: Well, you have some weird (and likely incorrect) column names. Everything inside the square brackets is space sensitive, so your column names start with a space, then the text _invoice mode_, a space, a forward slash, another space, and then the text _service level_